# Sync Server with Local DB when Push notification came : iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, background-process

I am working on an app, my requirement is when any push notification came then sync server with local DB in background even when app is killed.
     According to me, this is done by Silent notification, when any push notification came application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler called then sync DB with server. Please tell me if I am going on a wrong way. In this, I am facing an issue when my app is killed application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler not called.

Comment: See if this can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856204/applicationdidreceiveremotenotificationfetchcompletionhandler-not-called

Comment: Hi Ujjwal, In this link,  if the app was forcibly closed (i.e. by killing with the app switcher), the app will not be launched. (see SO answer) EDIT: I checked this again on iOS 7.1 to see if they fixed this, but it still remains the case that if the app is killed manually, app will NOT be woken up and application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: will not be called

Comment: So, How Will iOS perform background tasks after the user has force-quit the app when push notification came?